# How do you abandon a message in a dotnet isolated Servicebus triggered function?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, dotnet-isolated

Is there a best way to abandon a message in an Azure dotnet isolated function app? I'm currently throwing an exception to force the function to complete unsuccessfully as there is no way to access a MessageReciever like you do in an in-process azure function to manually complete or abandon a message.

Comment: These operations are currently not supported  refer this answer https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/293